# Select via google spreadsheet importxml function a field after a certain text

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use Google Sheets' `importxml` function to get the following data from a link:

```
Kategorie(n):   Mehrfamilienhaus
Schätzwert:     100.000,00 EUR
```

As I want to use XPath on other links I would like to structure it that it selects the text after the text `Schätzwert:` or `Kategorie(n):`. I tried the following:

```
=IMPORTXML(A2,"//tr/td[@class='tlabel' | text()='Schätzwert:']/following-sibling::div/text()")
```

I wanted to do something similar for `Kategorie(n):`.

The [link](http://www.ediktsdatei.justiz.gv.at/edikte/ex/exedi3.nsf/0/4ac26a63aa456986c1257ea1002459a4) in `A2`.

Answer (score 0):

For Mehrfamilienhaus

```
=importxml(A2,"//*[@id='diveddoc']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[22]/td[2]")
```

For 100.000,00 EUR

```
=importxml(A2,"//*[@id='diveddoc']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[20]/td[2]/div")
```

Since the data is in a table, you could also use
For Mehrfamilienhaus

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML(A2,"table",0),22,2)
```

For 100.000,00 EUR

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML(A2,"table",0),27,2)
```